# Count on a grandchild of a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, models

I have 3 models

```
Article
- has_many replies

Reply
- has_many votes

Vote
- belongs_to reply
```

I'm writing a method in the Article model that returns the total count of all the votes received in the the replies of an Article.

Before resorting to writing an SQL query, I wanted to check if there was a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do what I call a "convenience association". Like so:

```
Article

has_many :replies
has_many :votes, through: :replies


# Then you can just do:
article.votes.size
```

Use `size` over `count` in case the collection is already loaded. Using `count` ensures a new database hit, while `size` does not unless needed.

Comment: +1 for [`size`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-size) info. i thought `size` on a `has_many` always instantiated `ActiveRecord` objects.